# How to use spatial index to test procedure in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, spatial

I have a procedure to return list of vachile which is the nearest and i use spatial indeks to test this procedure
my procedure is that :

```
create procedure    [dbo].[p_search_vehicle]
@IdCustomer int,
 @idGroupVehicle int = null,
 @ResultCount int= null,
 @Radiant int= null 
 as
 begin
 if @IdCustomer is null
    begin
        print 'The argument cannot be null'
        return 
    end
 declare @start geography
 SET @start = (select location from Customer where idCustomer=@idCustomer )
 ---@Result null group null radiant null
    if @ResultCount is null and @idGroupVehicle is null and @Radiant is null
    select top 10 idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 is not null)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
             ---@Result null  radiant null
            else if @ResultCount is null and @Radiant is null
    select  top 10 idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where  idGroupVehicle= @idGroupVehicle and (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000  is not null)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
             ---@Radiant null  
            else if @Radiant is null
    select TOP(@ResultCount) idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where idGroupVehicle= @idGroupVehicle  and  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000  is not null)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
             ---@@idGroupVehicle  null @Radiant is null
            else if  @idGroupVehicle is null and @Radiant is null
    select TOP(@ResultCount) idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000  is not null)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
            ---@idGroupVehicle is null and @ResultCount is null
            else if  @idGroupVehicle is null and @ResultCount is null
    select top 10 idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000   <= @Radiant)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
        --- @idGroupVehicle is null 
            else if  @idGroupVehicle is null 
    select TOP(@ResultCount) idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000   <= @Radiant)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
            --- @Result is null 
            else if  @ResultCount is null 
    select TOP(10) idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where  idGroupVehicle= @idGroupVehicle and  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000   <= @Radiant)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
            --- all options
    else
    select TOP(@ResultCount) idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where idGroupVehicle= @idGroupVehicle  and  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000  <= @Radiant)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
 end
GO
```

i have table Vehicle and in my table i have  locationVehicle this record have type geography and  on this record i have spatial index like that

```
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [SIndx_Vehicle_locationVehicle] ON [dbo].[Vehicle]
(
    [locationVehicle]
)USING  GEOGRAPHY_AUTO_GRID 
WITH (
CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 12, PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

but when i test my procedur to see my plan i dont see my spatial index in this plan i dont know why can someone tell me why i dont see my spatial index with execution plan ?
i only see pk key of this table
[image]

Comment: `where (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 is not null)`? Why `/1000`? `NULL/1000 = NULL` where as `{any non-NULL value} / 1000 = {a non-NULL value}`. The `/1000` is *not* going to help the RDBMS here.

Comment: /1000 because I wanted to see kilometers in my return if i delete /1000 will be better ?

Comment: That doesn't exist why it's in the `WHERE` though, @Konrad .

Comment: what doesn't exist in where ? @Lamu i want to see distance to vehicle in kilometers and distance cant be null

Comment: but I have to use something like this from Vehicle  [WITH(INDEX(<SIndx_Vehicle_locationVehicle>))]  ?

Comment: *Why* are you using `/1000` **in the `WHERE`** when you are comparing against `NULL`? Again, `NULL / 1000 = NULL`. There are no non-`NULL` values you can divide by `1000` to create `NULL`, so why do it?

Comment: i comprasing to is not null not null

Comment: but i must use FROM Vehicle AS T WITH(INDEX(SIX_locationVehicle))  to work with saptail index ?

Comment: *"i comprasing to is not null not null"*, so ***why*** `/1000`?

Comment: i must divide /1000 becaouse i want to see result with  meters

Comment: *"
i must divide /1000 becaouse i want to see result with meters"*... `NULL/1000` **equals** `NULL`.... `NULL` kilomtetres = `NULL` metres... So, *why are you dividing by 1000 in the `WHERE` when you are comparing to `NULL`?* There are **no** non`-NULL` values you divide by `1000`  that result in `NULL`...

Comment: so what i must to do delete /1000 or what ?

Comment: As I've been saying, in the `WHERE` it is not needed;it only makes the query non-SARGable.

Comment: ok but i delete /1000 and i still don't have a spatial index in my plan why i cant see this index only pk

Comment: I feel the need to link [Geography Methods Supported by Spatial Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver15#geography) again because you must not have understood it when you asked this question previously. Having `/1000` everywhere is probably preventing it from using the spatial index.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the protracted discussion from the comments into an answer, the conversion of meters to kilometers in several places in your query is probably the reason here. Let's go through them in sequence:

1. `@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000  is not null`. Could this be better written as `@start is not null and locationVechicle is not null`? That is, if the two geospatial points exist, they will have a distance between them (perhaps 0, but even that's still not null`.
2. `order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000`. This is better written as `order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)`. As written, SQL has to calculate the distance between `@start` and every point in your table, divide by 1000, and then use that new calculated metric to sort. In short, the division has turned non-SARGable.

That said, I'd also remove the conversion of meters to kilometers from the database entirely and relegate to your application tier. Which a small computational burden, that's still CPU cycles on your expensive database server that could be done on your less expensive (and more easily scaled) app tier.

Comment: that is, you suggest that the line where is ```select @ start.STDistance (locationVehicle) / 1000``` remove /1000 and in the line where is ```where (@ start.STDistance (locationVehicle) / 1000 is not null) ``` change to ```@start is not null and locationVechicle is not null ``` and in order ```order by @ start.STDistance (locationVehicle)``` remove /1000 too ? ok i will check this but wheni use hint i have a spatial index in my execution plan